# How can I change my Pytorch module (with in-place operations) to be differentiable?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, dropout

My layer is like this (I am making an LSTM layer with dropout applied in every time-step, the input is passed through 10 times, and the average of the outputs is returned)

```
import torch
from torch import nn


class StochasticLSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size: int, hidden_size: int, dropout_rate: float):
        """
        Args:
        - dropout_rate: should be between 0 and 1
        """
        super(StochasticLSTM, self).__init__()

        self.iter = 10
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size

        if not 0 <= dropout_rate <= 1:
            raise Exception("Dropout rate should be between 0 and 1")
        self.dropout = dropout_rate
        self.bernoulli_x = torch.distributions.Bernoulli(
            torch.full((self.input_size,), 1 - self.dropout)
        )
        self.bernoulli_h = torch.distributions.Bernoulli(
            torch.full((hidden_size,), 1 - self.dropout)
        )

        self.Wi = nn.Linear(self.input_size, self.hidden_size)
        self.Ui = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size, self.hidden_size)

        self.Wf = nn.Linear(self.input_size, self.hidden_size)
        self.Uf = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size, self.hidden_size)

        self.Wo = nn.Linear(self.input_size, self.hidden_size)
        self.Uo = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size, self.hidden_size)

        self.Wg = nn.Linear(self.input_size, self.hidden_size)
        self.Ug = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size, self.hidden_size)

    def forward(self, input, hx=None):
        """
        input shape (sequence, batch, input dimension)
        output shape (sequence, batch, output dimension)
        return output, (hidden_state, cell_state)
        """

        T, B, _ = input.shape

        if hx is None:
            hx = torch.zeros((self.iter, T + 1, B, self.hidden_size), dtype=input.dtype)
        else:
            hx = hx.unsqueeze(0).repeat(self.iter, T + 1, B, self.hidden_size)

        c = torch.zeros((self.iter, T + 1, B, self.hidden_size), dtype=input.dtype)
        o = torch.zeros((self.iter, T, B, self.hidden_size), dtype=input.dtype)

        for it in range(self.iter):
            # Dropout
            zx = self.bernoulli_x.sample()
            zh = self.bernoulli_h.sample()

            for t in range(T):
                x = input[t] * zx
                h = hx[it, t] * zh

                i = torch.sigmoid(self.Ui(h) + self.Wi(x))
                f = torch.sigmoid(self.Uf(h) + self.Wf(x))

                o[it, t] = torch.sigmoid(self.Uo(h) + self.Wo(x))
                g = torch.tanh(self.Ug(h) + self.Wg(x))

                c[it, t + 1] = f * c[it, t] + i * g
                hx[it, t + 1] = o[it, t] * torch.tanh(c[it, t + 1])

        o = torch.mean(o, axis=0)
        c = torch.mean(c[:, 1:], axis=0)
        hx = torch.mean(hx[:, 1:], axis=0)

        return o, (hx, c)
```

When I optimizer the network, I have the error `one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation`. We can spot several inplace operations such as `o[it, t] = torch.sigmoid(self.Uo(h) + self.Wo(x))`.

How can I avoid this inplace operation when I want to find the average?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead, use a Python list to collect tensor results, and stack the list into one tensor at the end, for e.g. instead of

```
t = torch.zeros(5, 5)
for i in range(5):
    t[i,:] = ...
```

Do this

```
t = []
for i in range(5):
    t.append(...)
t = torch.stack(t)
```